# Grab all users by username from MVC template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm somewhat new to Entity Framework and MVC.  Is there a good way to grab all the users in the AspNet Users table to display all registered users?  Im using the  MVC5 template that Microsoft provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create controller, change db to your context

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
        return View(await db.User.ToListAsync());
}
```

Next add view to Index and use **List** as a Template. Right click on Index() and choose Add View. Fill form and your view will be generate.

I recomend you to watch some video courses about ASP.NET on Microsoft Virtual Academy.
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start

Comment: could you show me what you mean by "Next add view to Index and use List as a Template" also is db supposed to be the name of my dbcontext?